# Paint on an InkCanvas with finger (touch screen) not mouse - mouseMove instead of MouseClick

Tags: c#, wpf, touchscreen, inkcanvas

I am using an InkCanvas on a Wpf Window (c#).
This Canvas is working when I am draging the mouse to the canvas, and then CLICK the mouse to draw what ever I want.

I intend to put this on a touch screen. As I unsderstand, the touch on the screen (finger or pen) will act as Mouse-Move, and not Mouse-Click, therefore nothing will be painted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See if this link helps:  http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That assumption is wrong, all touch behaviors are interpreted as mouse interaction by default if you do not override it, a touch turns into MouseDown, so it will work (i have a touch-screen myself).